# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shape'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow and I met an error while trying to run some sample codes.

```
import tensorflow as tf

g1 = tf.Graph()
with g1.as_default():
    v = tf.get_variable("v", initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(shape=[1]))
```

Running the code above gives the error:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shape'.

The comment below says that tf.zeros_initializer does not accept 'shape' argument according to the documentation. I tried

```
v = tf.get_variable("v", initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
```

and it says ValueError: Shape of a new variable (v) must be fully defined, but instead was .

So, what kind of argument/expression should I use to define the shape without causing a type error?

I cannot find how to solve it online. Please help. Thank you

Comment: `tf.zero_initializer()` doesn't accept a `shape` argument, see the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeros_initializer). What did you hope the code would do?

Comment: Thank you for the documentation.This is a sample code from a book and I am also finding out what it is supposed to do. BTW can I have some examples on how to use tf.zero_initializer()? I tried removing "shape=[1]" or "shape=". Both don't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the book I'm using is a bit out of date. The following code appears to work so far.

```
v = tf.get_variable("v", shape=[1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
```

I will check if it actually works with more code added later.

Comment: Ok I just checked that it works. If you are also using the book from Caicloud, I hope this helps. In addition, the following part in the book runs `tf.initialize_all_variables().run()`. This should be updated to `tf.global_variables_initializer().run()`.

Answer (score 1):

In version 2.4.1 I use `tf.constant()` instead